# Как верстать пиксель в пиксель?

Tags: html, css

Посоветуйте различные расширения или другие пути верстки пиксель в пиксель

Comment: Советую почти любой плагин под ваш браузер, в названии которого есть Perfect или Pixel или они вместе. Да вот хотя бы взять PerfectPixel.

Answer (score 4):

Вот отличное расширение для Хрома, для верстки ["перфектпиксель"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/perfectpixel-by-welldonec/dkaagdgjmgdmbnecmcefdhjekcoceebi)